# Apache Spark forEach on RDDs of Tuple2 : returns one Value for all the Tuple2s in my RDD

Tags: java, apache-spark, tuples, rdd

I have this code that's been giving me an unexpectedly wrong result that i couldn't solve :

```
// A method that calls the collectDataRDD(logValues, rowData) method :

// ....
// my collectDataRDD(Values, rowData) method :
```

The problem is that when i try to run methods like getStatus() or getValidationDate() on Data Objects which are the values of my Tuple2, it only gives one output for all the objects in my JavaRDD which is wrong, because the JavaRDD contains multiple different Objects. However when i checked the keys of my tuple2 it gave me correct results.

I have tried everything and still couldn't figure it out. Can anyone please help me solve this.
THanks a lot in advance.

Comment: are you running this code in local or distributed mode?

Comment: I'm running it on local mode.

Answer (score 0):

Verify if

```
ticketsrdd.foreach((Tuple2<String, Data> rowData) -> {
    collectLogDataRDD(logValues, rowData);
}
```

is what you want to do. This function is called for each element one by one and Tuple2 will have only one entry in that case.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I want to run  collectLogDataRDD() on each Tuple2 of my rdd . So yes I only need one entry each time.

Comment: If I understand correctly, then you mean collectLogDataRDD is getting called only once. Is that correct?

Comment: Nop  collectLogDataRDD is called on each Tuple2 of my RDD . I used  " ticketsrdd.foreach ".

Comment: Okay, then in that case ticket.getStatus(); will have just one Data object, isn't it?

Comment: Yes one object for each Tuple2. But I don't have one Tuple2. It's supposed to do the same thing on every Tuple2 from my RDD

Comment: Let me try to reiterate it in a better way, please check another expatiation that I am adding. Can you please answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
JavaRDD<Tuple2<String, Data>> ticketsrdd=TransformToRDD.transformToRDD(transformer.transform());
DataStore.setData(tickets);
```

Will be kind of `Map<String, Tuple2>`. And your Tuple2 will have one key as String and one value as Data.

Now when you say  `Data ticket = rowData._2`; you are getting 1 Data object from 1 tuple. So for each tuple in `ticketsrdd` its going to called `collectLogDataRDD`.

Lets say ticketsrdd has 100 element then its going to call  collectLogDataRDD 100 times, and each time `ticket.getStatus();` will also be be call.

This is what code is doing. What different behavior do you expect?

Comment: That's exactly what i'm expecting. However, the code only treats one Tuple2 and ignores the rest.

Comment: Ok, what do you see when you do ticketsrdd.count?

Comment: ticketsrdd.count gives 106 as a result.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Have you tried putting loggers in collectLogDataRDD and to check if it gets called multiple times and prints values of Data object. Hopefully you will find out your answer with that. Good luck!!

Comment: Also, check your transformer.transform();, I hope nothing miscellaneous is happening over there.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think that it's a serialization problem. I emplemented Serializable in every class. But it's not working. Do you have any suggestions ?